# How to edit a field in my xml file in my table datos_usuario where num_id =""0801918813437"

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hello I am developing an app in vb.net that creates and manipulates xml files. The file which name is users has several datos_usarios table one per user.

What I want to do is to create a code in vb.net that allows me to change the field Nombre(name) that in the inner text is Gerardo to John where the table Datos_usuario has a field with num_id "0801198813437".

The reason why I want to verify that is to make sure it's modifying the right datos_usuario table since I have one datos usuario table per user and for example I can have several users called Gerardo but the num_id will be a unique field so that's why I want to change Nombre where num_id = "08011918813437"
this is the xml file

[XML FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Gkj.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Users>
  <Datos_Usuario>
    <Nombre>Gerardo</Nombre>
    <Apellido>Godoy</Apellido>
    <Telefono>99404469</Telefono>
    <correo>gjafet2005@gmail.com</correo>
    <direccion>Res. La Hacienda</direccion>
    <user>jerry</user>
    <contraseña>godoy</contraseña>
    <num_id>0801198813437</num_id>
  </Datos_Usuario>
  <Datos_Usuario>
    <Nombre>Fanny</Nombre>
    <Apellido>Saission</Apellido>
    <Telefono>99404469</Telefono>
    <correo>gjafet2005@gmail.com</correo>
    <direccion>Res. La Hacienda</direccion>
    <user>fany</user>
    <contraseña>sai</contraseña>
    <num_id>0801198813007</num_id>
  </Datos_Usuario>
  <Datos_Usuario>
    <Nombre>jonathan</Nombre>
    <Apellido>godoy</Apellido>
    <Telefono>33396485</Telefono>
    <correo>jonathan_jared@hotmail.com</correo>
    <direccion>res. la haccienda</direccion>
    <user>jon11</user>
    <contraseña>jaimico2009</contraseña>
    <num_id>0801199804519</num_id>
  </Datos_Usuario>
  <Datos_Usuario>
    <Nombre>ROCIO</Nombre>
    <Apellido>GODOY</Apellido>
    <Telefono>31720388</Telefono>
    <correo>rociogodoy92@gmail.com</correo>
    <direccion>la hacienda</direccion>
    <user>ROCIO</user>
    <contraseña>ABELARD</contraseña>
    <num_id>0801199205694</num_id>
  </Datos_Usuario>
</Users>
```

want to replace Gerardo to John in Nombre where num_id ="0801198813437"

Comment: hello am new in this forum learning how to use it this is the link of the image of my xml file.....https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Gkj.jpg

Comment: No problem, just copy-paste the XML *text* from the Notepad as text into your question, so it will become selectable as normal text. You can surround it by `<pre>` ... `</pre>` tags to keep the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`System.Xml.Linq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq) Namespace:

```
Dim x = XDocument.Load("C:\users.xml")

For Each user In x.<Users>.<Datos_usuario>
    If user.<num_id>.Value = "0801198813437" Then
        user.<Nombre>.Value = "John"
    End If
Next

x.Save("C:\users.xml")
```

For more information you can check [XML Child Axis Property (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xml-axis/xml-child-axis-property)

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to achieve it. I continue working in a code with a data set and actually did what I was looking for ill leave my code in case someone else needs it I put some error providers to avoid user to change the fields with empty data ""

```
                Dim namefile
            namefile = "C:\Users\GERARDO\Documents\prueba app\users.xml"

            Dim loadxml As XmlDocument

            loadxml = New XmlDocument()

            Dim DTB = New DataTable

            DTB = loadxml
            'Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument
            Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
            Dim ts As DataSet
            Dim reader As StringReader
            xmlDoc = New XmlDocument()
            xmlDoc.Load(namefile)



            Dim see As String
            Dim see2 As String

            ts = New DataSet()

            'reader = New StringReader(xmlDoc.InnerXml)
            reader = New StringReader(xmlDoc.InnerXml)
            'reader = New XmlElement
            ts.ReadXml(reader)

            For Each t As DataTable In ts.Tables
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", t.TableName, t.Rows.Count))

                For Each r As DataRow In t.Rows
                    see = r.Item(0)
                    see2 = r.Item(7)
                    If My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtnum_id.Text = see2 Then
                        Dim denyentance As Integer
                        If My.Forms.MantUsuario.TxtName.Text = "" Then
                            My.Forms.MantUsuario.ErrorProvider1.SetError(My.Forms.MantUsuario.TxtName, "Favor llenar el nombre")
                            denyentance = 1
                        End If
                        If My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtapellido.Text = "" Then
                            My.Forms.MantUsuario.ErrorProvider1.SetError(My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtapellido, "Llenar el Apellido")
                            denyentance = 1
                        End If
                        If My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtcorreo.Text = "" Then
                            My.Forms.MantUsuario.ErrorProvider1.SetError(My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtcorreo, "Llenar el Correo")
                            denyentance = 1
                        End If
                        If My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtdir.Text = "" Then
                            denyentance = 1
                        End If
                        If My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtphone.Text = "" Then
                            denyentance = 1
                        End If
                        If denyentance = 1 Then
                            MsgBox("Debe llenar todos los campos", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

                        Else
                            MsgBox("Se ha Guardado Exitosamente", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                            r.Item(0) = My.Forms.MantUsuario.TxtName.Text
                            r.Item(1) = My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtapellido.Text
                            r.Item(2) = My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtphone.Text
                            r.Item(3) = My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtcorreo.Text
                            r.Item(4) = My.Forms.MantUsuario.Txtdir.Text
                            ts.AcceptChanges()
                            ts.BeginInit()

                        End If

                    End If

                Next
            Next
            ts.EndInit()
            ts.WriteXml(namefile)
```